# Modifying LayerDrawable layer on Android 2.3 .X (Gingerbread) and lower

Tags: android, android-layout, compatibility, android-drawable, layerdrawable

I have the following [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/image_source"
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/default"
        android:left="14dp"
        android:right="14dp"
        android:top="6dp">
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/metaphor_photo_portrait"/>

</layer-list>
```

I need to be able to dynamically sustitute the image in `@+id/image_source` from the code. I succeeed to do on Honeycomb+ devices using:

```
mLayerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.image_source, drawable);
mLayerDrawable.invalidateSelf();
```

However, this does not work on Gingerbread devices as `setDrawableByLayerId` is unstable for Gingerbread devices ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362144/android-layerdrawable-setdrawablebylayerid-not-working-on-htc-sensation-and-oth), [link 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/lF8LpqieyQg)). I am advised to construct the `LayerDrawable` from scratch. I started doing that and am currently faced with the problem of setting the `intristicInset` of the first layer.

I tried using

```
mLayerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, dp14, dp6, dp14, dp6);
```

Where `dpxx` are constants I calculate myself. However it seems this method is not working on Gingerbread either ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826075/layerdrawable-setlayerinset-not-working-on-android-2-3)).

Thus I decided to try to do it the other way - set the bounds of the restangle of the drawable I set on the first layer:

```
drawable.setBounds(dp14, dp6, dp90 - dp14, dp90 - dp6);
```

Perfect, however it seems that bounds settings on `LayerDrawable` layer are ignored ([link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fUxtJstdkBM/discussion))

Now I am advised to use combination of two image viwes. However my `LayerDrawable` is part of [`LevelListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) and I think that I can not include layout in such.

All in all this leave me not being able to modify the contents of my `LayerDrawable` in any way on pre-Honeycomb devices. Any advises on how should I proceed are appreciated!

Comment: It may be easier for you to just use two `ImageView` widgets in a `FrameLayout`, to achieve the layer effect.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your suggestion. However note what I mention - I am using `LevelListDrawable` for container for my `LayerDrawable`. I am not aware of any way in which I can include `FrameLayout` as level in `LevelListDrawable`...

Comment: My apologies, I missed that. Where are you using the `LevelListDrawable`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Basically what you see here is portion of my solution for optimal thumbnail displayal of file system. I have few file types that have `LayerDrawable`s as thumbnails - e.g. music file is rendered in metaphor of a cd. I am using the `LevelListDrawable` in order to seek performance optimization.

Comment: But then why do you have to change the image source at runtime? It's not like a file is going to magically change file type on the fly.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am substituting the general thumbnail with real thumbnail for the specific audio/ video/image file. However, I am fetching those remotely and so I am doing it on the background. Thus I need to substitude the default with real instance thumbnail after some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
drawable.setBounds(mLayerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.image_source).getBounds());
mLayerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.image_source, drawable);        
mLayerDrawable.invalidateSelf();
```

reference:
https://github.com/ytRino/LayerDrawableSample/blob/master/src/net/nessness/android/sample/layerdrawable/LayerDrawableSampleActivity.java

Comment: Nice hack you found here. Worked for me as a charm.
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally we got it to wok in some very weird way:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(layerDrawableResourceId);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.image_source, drawable);
Drawable[] layers = {
   layerDrawable };
LayerDrawable layerDrawableNew = new LayerDrawable(layers);
```

A colleague of mine found that if we create new `LayerDrawable`, set the not-working method to it and then wrap this `LayerDrawable` in yet another, the visualization is correct (both the image is changed and the paddings preserved). Quite a tweaking around and a lot of "Don't touch this it's magic", but this is the best solution we could work out.